# How omnet initialize modules and model?

Tags: module, sequence, omnet++, event-simulation

I read manual and inside the manual there is described using pseudo code that first simulation step, when simulation start is "network initialization" from system module to the sub-modules. In simulation example that I have there is "simulation.ned" and it s used for defining some simulation variables and package.ned where I have network defined.

Questions are:

- When simulation start how omnet intialize modules (maybee seek for all *.ned files to create full network)?
- when module is created does he wait for all sub-modules to be generated or he immediately apply configuration ( initialize() method) or wait for all modules to be created and then continue with configuration?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the simulation preparing (and before the first event is processed) the following steps are performed:

1. The simulation environment looks into `omnetpp.ini` and checks the name of `network`, for example:

   ```
   [General]
   network = ARPTest
   ```
2. The simulation environment scans `NED`files and looks for the file which contains:

   ```
   network ARPTest {
    // ...
   }
   ```
3. The simulation environment calls `initialize()` for all submodules mentioned in this network. There is [the important rule](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:init-finish:invocation-order):

> A compound module's `initialize()` function runs *before* that of its submodules.

---

It is also worth remembering that in `OMNeT++` there is an opportunity to use [multi stage initialization](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:multi-stage-init). It is useful when one submodule cannot be initialized without some information from another submodule, for example: a routing submodule need the addresses of host's interfaces to initialize.